# Loki Daemon Node Crashed with Error Adding Block with hash and stuck at 99.99% sync

Tags: daemon, monero-forks, loki

My Loki daemon node crashed and when restarting I get the following error of: **Error Adding Block with Hash:** -- I tried restarting a few times and waited. How can I fix this?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After trying a few times to sync and constantly getting stuck at 99% with that same error. I had to delete the Loki blockchain and just download it again. Instead of resyncing, just download the loki blockchain directly from: https://imaginary.stream/loki/

I did the following:

- cd ~/.loki/lmdb
- rm data.mdb
- wget https://imaginary.stream/loki/data.mdb

Then start your loki daemon again.